# How can I get access to Servet Context in apache cxf?

Tags: web-services, cxf

How can I get access to Servlet context in my apache cxf web service application?

I am using apache cxf 2.2.7 and Json as the data transfer format.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`ServletContextAware`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/3.0.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.java) interface: Spring beans registered in Web context and implementing this interface get the access to `ServletContext`. More aggressive approach is to request bean with name `servletContext` from Web Context or use `ServletContextParameterFactoryBean`.

Otherwise (if you don't use Spring+CXF, which is unusual) you need to implement `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` and register this implementation in `<web-app> → <listener> → <listener-class>`. The implementation should save `ServletContext` to be later used by your WebService.

Comment: Thanks a lot but still I am not clear how to achieve this. Could you please share some sample code explaining how to achieve the result?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any code that does it. Do you use [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) in your application?

Comment: Yes. I use spring with apache-cxf.

Comment: Do you publish your WS using `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean`? This factory has `serviceBean` property, where you pass the reference to WS implementation. This implementation should implement `ServletContextAware` interface.